# no connection error in inserting credit card information in android device

Tags: android, in-app

i am trying to implement `in-app` in android my test example is running perfectly now(finally).
**BUT** now i have another problem when i insert the information of credit card in my android device
(Sony xperia sola 4.0.4 , HTC salsa 2.3.3, Galaxy_tab2 4.0.4) it was field due to this error . 
[image]

i just check internet every time and it's working fine,
first i am not sure about my code so i try to download App from Google play even though error become accouter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

yes finally it's done the problem is with my test account , i just no that the account has to enter it's credit card information as part of Gmail signup